# DRY Kleisli wrappers with lens

Tags: haskell

This currently does what I intend:

```
import Control.Arrow (Kleisli, runKleisli)
import Control.Applicative (WrappedArrow(WrapArrow))
import Control.Lens.Traversal (preview)

nested :: Request -> Maybe Response
nested = runKleisli . unwrapArrow
       $ WrapArrow (Kleisli (preview (prefixed "/name") >=> app1))
     <|> WrapArrow (Kleisli (preview (prefixed "/surname") >=> app2))

  where
    prefixed :: Text -> Prism' Request Request
    prefixed = _

    app1,app2 :: Request -> Maybe Response
    app1 = _
    app2 = _
```

The idea here is to implement a kind of nested HTTP routing. Given the already existing *applications* `app1` and `app2`, I want to reroute the incoming `Request` to either of those applications based on whether the path of the `Request` is prefixed with `"/name"` or `"/surname"`. The `prefixed` `Prism'` strips such prefix from the `Request` path if present, otherwise it fails.

However I'd like to get rid, somehow, of `WrapArrow`, `Kleisli` and `preview`, and possibly, `runKleisli . unwrapArrow`. I suspect that this can be done with `Control.Lens.Wrapped` or `Data.Profuntor` but I still can't see exactly how.

I wouldn't like to a add an extra dependency for this case but I'm currently using `lens` in my project, so anything from `lens` or its dependencies is welcome.

Comment: @RubberDuck, hope it's more understandable now.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review @DannyNavarro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came out with this:

```
nested :: Request -> Maybe Response
nested = nest [ (prefixed "/name", app1)
              , (prefixed "/surname", app2)
              ]

  where
    nest xs request =
        getAlt $ foldMap (Alt . (\(p,a) -> reroute p a request)) xs

    reroute p app = preview p >=> app
```

`Alt` is only available in `base-4.8.0.0`, however it shouldn't be difficult to implement your own `Alt`.

Comment: I'm a leaving it open for a few days more in case someone comes with something better.